# converts 123abcf3r2e to 123ABC-F3R2E

Tags: regex

How to convert an alphanumeric combination to uppercase with a dash after every 5 digit using regex eg.:

`123abe5r4t` to `123AB-E5R4T`

Comment: Not sure to be easy with only a regular expression...

Answer (score 0):

Use `[0-9a-z]{1,5}` as the *match* part (with `g` option) and `\U\0-` as the *replace* part.

`\U` (in the *replace* part) takes care about conversion to upper case.

`\0` copies the whole match and `-` adds the minus.

The only thing to do afterwards is to remove the terminating minus (after the last match).

For a working example see https://regex101.com/r/8WXUhd/1

## Edit

I reworked the above example to JavaScript flavour of regex:

```
var a = '123abe5r4txx234';
var b = a.replace( /[0-9a-z]{1,5}/g, u => u.toUpperCase() + '-').slice(0, -1);
print(a);
print(b);
```

It prints (source and result):

```
123abe5r4txx234
123AB-E5R4T-XX234
```

Comment: Thanks, that was a great help @Valdi_Bo

Comment: i need to write it in jsx

Comment: Thankyou ver much. Sorry i wasn't able to reply early due to internet issues.